# how to change rancher network plugin flannel to waeve?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have an up and running rancher cluster (Airgap mode) in my own server. As I know after you launch the cluster, you cannot change your network provider.
Is there any solution that I'll be change my network plugin from flannel to weave?
I  don't want bootstrap a new cluster again.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe it is not possible to do on flight and keep it working. You should bootstrap new cluster, if you want run it in the proper way without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a backup of the Rancher server cluster, build a new one with the new network provider, and restore the backup into it. Follow the [documentation for backup/restore](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/backups/backups/ha-backups/) so that you don't have to alter any downstream cluster configuration.